# Forwarding a port internally - Cisco-881

Tags: cisco, port-forwarding, ios

I have a Cisco 881 on which I forward traffic coming from outside to an internal IP, but if an internal IP accesses the external IP, it gets the Cisco HTTP Server (or a broken connection if i set `no ip http server`.  Is there a way to forward both internal and external visitors to the same server?  To get around it now, I have an internal DNS server, but I would like to do away with it.

Comment: Whats up with the downvote? If there is something wrong with my question, I'll fix it

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at postings #7 & #8 of the thread for possible solutions/ideas.

http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/cisco/nsp/90965

Comment: I've realized that I want to hairpin the traffic, but the problem is all the examples I have found are for old ASA/PIXs.  There are no examples for this router/IOS (12.4)

Comment: The example/approach of creating a second NAT should be more generic.